# Prevent NexentaStor analytics page from timing out

Tags: storage, zfs, nexenta, dtrace

[NexentaStor](http://www.nexenta.com/corp/downloads/nexentastor-download) has a handy profiling interface that serves as a front to certain [dtrace scripts](http://dtrace.org/blogs/). It's handy for monitoring realtime IOPS or I/O throughput of the appliance.

Unfortunately, this interface times out after a few minutes leaving a blank statistics screen and resetting the charts.

Any suggestions on how to prevent this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a support ticket with Nexenta to try to get an official answer since I tried to search through the UI and configuration files for a tunable...

> Currently there is no way of increasing the timeouts for the analytics
>   in the current version. This will be rectified in a future version.